# Getting error "timeStamp not ISO format" when using a websocket api call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, iso

The format that I require:
`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD`

Link to API docs: https://docs.blocknative.com/websocket

My Code:

```
def get_required_parameters():
    required_parameters = {
        'timestamp':datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z',
        'dappId': apikey,
        'version':'1',
        'blockhain': {'system': 'ethereum', 'network':'bsc-main'}
    }
    return required_parameters

ws = create_connection('wss://api.blocknative.com/v0')
initial_msg = {
        'categoryCode': 'initialize',
        'eventCode': 'checkDappId'
    }.update(get_required_parameters())
ws.send(initial_msg)
```

Error that I'm getting from the websocket connection:

```
{"version":0,"serverVersion":"0.109.6","status":"ok","showUX":true,"connectionId":"xyz"}
{"version":0,"serverVersion":"0.109.6","timeStamp":"2021-06-12T23:30:42.631Z","connectionId":"xyz","origin":"http://api.blocknative.com","status":"error","raw":"","reason":"timeStamp not ISO format"}
```

How do I get the proper format of the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

By default the fractional second part provided by [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) is in microseconds (6 digits).

When I look at the second API response, they return the timestamp `"2021-06-12T23:30:42.631Z"` in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.fffZ`, not as you provided `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ffffffZ`.
Probably the expect it in the same way.

You can add the argument `timespec='milliseconds'` to `isoformat()` to get milliseconds (3 digits).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'
2021-06-13T00:06:16.398Z
```